# Replace function references with its returning values on nested JS object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of object like this:

```
[
  {
    header: {
      car: 'Start',
      carName: startName
    },
    data: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    header: {
      car: 'End',
      carName: endName
    },
    data: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    header: {
      car: 'Finish',
      carName: finishName
    },
    data: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
```

Where startName, endName, and finishName are function references. I want to replace the whole array with actually calling the function so it should be like this:

```
[
  {
    header: {
      car: 'Start',
      carName: startName()
    },
    data: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    header: {
      car: 'End',
      carName: endName()
    },
    data: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    header: {
      car: 'Finish',
      carName: finishName()
    },
    data: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
```

I thought of creating some sort of mapping function and new object but looks like its too much. Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: In the fisrt object (let's name it `obj`) if called `obj.header.startName` it will call the function `startName` with no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second block of code is completely valid. You **can** assign the return of the `startName`, `endName` and `finishName` functions called respectively for each object's attribute `carName`.

If you want to declare them as function references and then replace them with their returning values later in the code, you can do:

```
let modified = arrayOfValues.map(value => {
  value.header.carName = value.header.carName();
  return value;
})
```

Assuming `arrayOfValues` is the whole array in the example.

**Important note**: take in account that the original `arrayOfValues` will also be modified (e.g to have `carName` attribute value replaced), since `map` does not make a *deep copy* of the original array and `header` is a sub-document. If you want to keep the original `arrayOfValues` intact, you'll have to use a library (e.g `lodash`). More on the discussion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript).

Comment: Thanks GusSL that works! I want to do the same for data which is array of objects. I am assuming we can just do the same logic for that as well.

Comment: @nativeGuy absolutely. It will work as well. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your question.